# How to create a price slider without using extension on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, price-slider

I want to create a price slider without using any third party extension and would like to create it on my own in Magento 2. Could anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add new functionalities to Magento without using extensions. If you do not want to add a new extension to your store, it may be possible to make the changes in the theme that you are currently using. By the way, on Magento 2, themes are "extensions" (modules) too.

Your question is not very clear, can you please give more details?

1. Where is this price slider going to be displayed?
2. What is the purpose of it?
3. Why you can't just add a new extension to Magento?

If possible, please, create a mock-up using Photoshop and add to the question so we can see what you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry to hear the question isn't clear. I have updated it. Please guide me

Comment: Of course. Could you please answer the 3 questions in my previous comment?

Comment: 1. We want the price slider displayed on category page 2. Select the range of the price 3. Though there are free extensions to make it, we want it create without using extension.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2 without using extension not possible. If you want via custom module than check with below link.

ElasticSuite extension: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite adds possibility to create numeric attributes, and filter them using sliders in layered navigation.

**hope its very helpful to you**